# Action delegate c# to vb.net conversion

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, delegates

Im having problem converting this to vb.net

c#

global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{                       
    config.Routes.Clear();            
}
```

vb.net

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest()
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)          
End Sub

Shared Function Register() As Action(Of HttpConfiguration)

End Function
```

I'm having problem in the version of vb.net on the register method. How can I access the parameter of the HttpConfiguration just like in c#.

Comment: `Action(Of HttpConfiguration)` is a generic, and your VB declaration of Register says that it returns a delegate of that type. The C# equivalent would be something more like `delegate Action<HttpConfiguration> Register()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the [`AddressOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) operator:

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest()
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)
    config.Routes.Clear()
End Sub
```